# How to change the subnet and the IP address of a docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have a docker container created with docker-compose running on a host.

The docker container obtained has its own network:

```
docker exec -it containername /bin/bash

root@4913fd78f383:/# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
155: eth0@if156: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:14:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.20.0.2/16 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So, the container occupies the IP 172.20.0.2/16 in the host.

My problem is that in this way **my host can't connect on the real 172.20.x.y hosts in the network** where the host is connected.

So, the container (with its own ip) hide other real addresses.

**I need to change the IP address of the existing container, possibly without deleting/recreating it.**

I have created my container with docker compose, so I use these commands to run/stop the container:

```
docker start containername
docker stop containername
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In general you have two options:

1. Using docker. Create a network with a custom subnet then from docker-compose join that network. [for more details](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/)
2. Using docker-compose. Define the network settings. [for more details](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address)

In your case specifically you have to do the following:

1. Create a network using docker cli.

```bash
    docker network create -d bridge --subnet 172.25.0.0/16 my_custom_network
```

2. Make the container join the network

```bash
    docker network connect my_custom_network my_running_container
```

3. Remove the container from the old network

> You can get the name of the old network using `docker inspect my_running_container`

```bash
    docker network disconnect old_network my_running_container
```

4. Delete unwanted network that `docker-compose` have created.

```bash
    docker network rm old_network
```

5. Reconfigure `docker-compose.yml` to use the new network in order to keep the same settings if someone used `docker-compose up` again.

For more details about the above options check [Work with Networks](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/)

> Note that you can also configure the default docker0 as explained in [here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/)